# relación con 3 tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

tengo una base de datos en mysql de los estados de la republica mexicana, primera tabla los 32 estados(32 datos), segunda tablas los municipios de cada estado (2463 datos), tercera tablas los códigos postales de cada municipio (30937), lo que quiero hacer es una consulta de un código postal y sepa de que municipio es y a que estado pertenece, pero mi tercer tabla no se como relacionarla con la de municipios, ejemplo de las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ALGUNOS DATOS DE CADA TABLA

[image: estados]

[image: municipios]

[image: codigo postal]

lo que hice al ultimo es relacionar mi id_municipio con el c_municipio (como lo mencionan en los comentarios, no me resulto) por que tengo ahí un problema en cada estado hay un municipio 1 por lo menos entonces c_municipio se repite para cada municipio varias veces dependiendo cuantos municipios hay en cada estado y al realizar la consulta toma el primer registro de la tabla estado entonces quiero ver si de que manera puedo hacer la consulta para que no pase eso

Comment: Bienevenido a SO, lo primero sería indicar lo que has intentado. De todas maneras por lo que veo el c_municipio de la tabla cp es similar al id_municipio de la tabla municipios, por lo que me imagino que se relacionan entre ellas a través de ese campo. (es una suposición)

Comment: Cual es el problema? No te entiendo.

Comment: cual es la forma correcta de hacer un select pasando por las 3 tablas, quiero una consulta de un código postal utilizando inner join

Comment: Necesitas una tabla relacion uno a muchos, de un lado el id del municipio y del otro lado el id del codigo postal. Por lo que el id del municipio se repetira n veces, donde n es la cantidad de codigos postales que tiene ese municipio.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM estados e 
INNER JOIN municipios m ON e.id_estado = m.estado_id 
INNER JOIN cp ON CAST(e.clave AS UNSIGNED) = cp.c_estado 
       AND CAST(m.clave AS UNSIGNED) = cp.c_municipio
```

No tengo como probarlo ahora mismo pero si algo no funciona probaremos otra cosa.